# Why is this class variable the same across different instances?

Tags: python, oop, class

Why does i remain the same even after a new instance of the class is created?

```
class Test(object):
    i = 0
    def add(self):
        Test.i += 1
```

Running this code

```
t = Test()
print t.i
t.add()
t2 = Test()
print t2.i
print t.i
```

Gives

```
0
1
1
```

Why didn't both t.i and t2.i equal 0? Shouldn't they have equaled 0 because the line `t2 = Test()` would have reset i to 0?

Comment: It's a *class variable*, as you correctly said yourself - it belongs to the class, not a specific instance of this class.

Comment: Please, give an eye on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is a class variable, not an instance variable. It is bound to the class itself (which is why you can write `Test.i`, even if no instances of `Test` exist).

You have to make `i` an instance variable:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def add(self):
        self.i += 1
```

Comment: I get that but when "t2 = Test()" is run, wouldn't the line "i = 0" be run again and reset i = 0?

Comment: @student: Nope. Your class is defined once. The stuff inside of `__init__` is run each time you initialize a new instance of your class.

Comment: Why would you expect that line to run again? The **class** is only created once (it would be pretty useless otherwise, since instances would belong to different classes!).

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying a property of the entire class, instead of a property of the instance. Try this:

```
class Test(object):
    i = 0
    def add(self):
        self.i += 1
```

Python automatically passes the instance as the argument `self` to the method. Within the method, you can therefore refer to a property of the instance as `self.i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test(object):
    i = 0
    def add(self):
        Test.i += 1

print "Test.i  == ",Test.i
print "'i' in dir(Test) == ",'i' in dir(Test)
print "'i' in Test.__dict__  == ",'i' in Test.__dict__

t1 = Test()
print '\n# t1 = Test() executed'
print "t1.i  == ",t1.i
print "'i' in dir(t1) == ",'i' in dir(t1)
print "'i' in t1.__dict__  == ",'i' in t1.__dict__
```

result

```
Test.i  ==  0
'i' in dir(Test) ==  True
'i' in Test.__dict__  ==  True

# t1 = Test() executed
t1.i  ==  0
'i' in dir(t1) ==  True
'i' in t1.__dict__  ==  False
```

.

The attribute of name `__dict__` of an object is the dictionary that represents the namespace of this object, that is to say it contains the attributes of the object.

Also, we have:

> dir([object])
>
> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called
>   and must return the list of attributes.

So, how is it possible that `dir(t1)` contains the attribute **i** and `t1.__dict__` doesn't ?
While all two `dir(Test)` and `Test.__dict__` contain the attribute **i** ?

.

That's for the same reason that answers to your question:

The behavior of returning the attribute of an object is awkward.
And `` `dir(object) ``reflects this awkwardness:

> The default dir() mechanism behaves differently with different types
>   of objects, as it attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than
>   complete, information:
>
> •If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the
>   module’s attributes.
>   •If the object is a type or class object, the
>   list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the
>   attributes of its bases.
>   •Otherwise, the list contains *the object’s
>   attributes’ names* , **the names of its class’s attributes**, and
>   recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

.

Then, the answer to your question is in two parts:

1) `dir(t1)` gives what is considered as the attributes of the object but the REAL NAMESPACE of the object, exposed as `t1.__dict__` doesn't contain the attribute **i**, which is, as it has already been answered, in fact, a class' atribute.

Hence the pseudo-attributes **i** of two instances **t1** and **t2** appear equals because the expressions `t1.i` and `t2.i` are in fact evaluated as `Test.i`,
in the same way that `dir(t1)` and `dir(t2)` include the class's attribute `Test.i`
.

2) how the expression `t1.i` is evaluated as `Test.i` ??
Because of that (which constitutes the additional info of my answer):

> A class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes.
>
> http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

It means that when an attribute isn't found in the namespace of an object, it is searched in the namespace of the class whose the object is an instance.